# Warning: [react-router] Location "/D:/original/22-02-2017/job2.html" did not match any routes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, react-router

I am working with typescript-with-react. And i m using webpack as a compiler . And my directory structure is as follows:
d:/original/22-02-2017/
      - 
[image]

**and my entry point in web.config.js is ./src/index.tsx file.**
**my components placed inside src/components/demo.tsx** 
[image]
[image]

---

and my index.tsx file is as follows

[image]

---

and inside /job2.html i have following links
[image]

but when i am trying to run program it gives me following error
Warning: [react-router] Location "/D:/original/22-02-2017/job2.html" did not match any routes

and i am not using server port i am just running my app at
file:///D:/original/22-02-2017/job2.html

i have tried many  but not get succeed. please help me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your router doesn't have a path for `/job2.html`. It only got `/`, `/stuff`, and `/contact/`.

Comment: [@LeeHanKyeol]how can i fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is the very old question for React router. Now we can use [React-Router-DOM](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) for routing with react. It is very easy to understand and very simple to use.